# Convert tokens words into list of word

Tags: python

How to convert a list of tokens to a sorted list in python

```
token_words ={'woo', 'us', 'feel', 'light', 'rain'}
```

Desire outcome :

```
woo
us
feel
light
rain
```

Comment: In what sense is your desired outcome "sorted"? And have you tried `sorted(token_words)`??

Answer (score 0):

You should use list or tuple data structure to solve the problem

```
token_words =['woo', 'us', 'feel', 'light', 'rain']
print(" ".join(list(token_words)))

token_words =('woo', 'us', 'feel', 'light', 'rain')
print(" ".join(list(token_words)))
```

if you use the set data structure as you have used , it will give different outputs
every time you run this code

```
token_words ={'woo', 'us', 'feel', 'light', 'rain'}
print(" ".join(list(token_words)))
```

This is because set uses hashing internally to store the data , however that can be solved using frozen set data structure